# Solving $2^k +k \equiv 0 \pmod {323}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all $k$ such that
$$2^k + k \equiv 0 \pmod{323}.$$

---

I noticed that $323 = 17\cdot 19$ so I thought about using the Chinese Remainder theorem by considering $2^k+k$ modulo 17 and 19. I got $k \equiv 16 \pmod{17}$ and $k\equiv 18 \pmod{19}$, which gives $k\equiv 322 \pmod{323}$. However, after trying this, the given solution was not valid : $2^{322} + 322 \equiv 156 \not \equiv 0 \mod{323}$.

Can someone explain why this didn't work, and what I can do to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: could you share your solutions?

Comment: CRT should work, assuming that you applied it correctly (which I'm guessing you didn't). In particular, note that $2^k \pmod{17}$ has a cycle length of 16. So, please show your solution.

Comment: I got $k \equiv 16 \pmod {17}$ and $k \equiv 18 \pmod {19}$ when splitting it up. Then, $k \equiv 322 \pmod{323}$ but that doesn't work.

Comment: Is it true that $ 2^{ 16 + 17} + (16 + 17) \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$? See my previous comment.

Comment: Oh It isn't, I didn't consider that. Then what should I do to get all solutions to the problem?

Comment: Side note: [Interesting that wolfram solved $2^k+k\equiv 0 \pmod{17}$ incorrectly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5Ek%2Bk+%3D+0+mod+17). They made the same assumption/error as you did. Likewise their solution $ \pmod{323}$ is incorrect.

Comment: You will need to solve for $2^k + k \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$ working in $\pmod{17 \times 16}$, and do the same for $ \pmod{19}$ working in $\pmod{19 \times 18}$, to find the general answer $ \pmod{17\times 19 \times 144}$.  That's how I would (theoretically) apply CRT.

Comment: How would you go about solving $2^k+k \mod {17}$ in $\mod 17\times 16$? I am not sure how it works.

Comment: 43,   52,   582,   671,   1820,   2758,   3438,   3452,   3574,   3579,   3721,   3846,   4265,   4405,   4949,   5431,   5625,   5975,   6309,   7335,   7496,   8067,   8345,   8448,   9029,   9286,   9563,   9890,   10055,   10624,   10657,   10842,   11054,   11304,   11341,   11440,

Comment: Find all values from 1 to $17\times 16$ such that $ 2^k + k \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$. Each $ a \in [1,16]$ will lift up to some solution $k\equiv a \pmod{17}$.  It's tedious (which is why I'm only theoretically doing it, but am not motivated enough to actually do it).

Comment: 43,   52,   582,   671,   1820,   2758,   3438,   3452,   3574,   3579,   3721,   3846,   4265,   4405,   4949,   5431,   5625,   5975,   6309,   7335,   7496,   8067,   8345,   8448,   9029,   9286,   9563,   9890,   10055,   10624,   10657,   10842,   11054,   11304,   11341,   11440,   11712,   12367,   12686,   12697,   13018,   13381,   13652,   13698,   13834,   14106,   14323,   14407,   14604,   14867,   16227,   16233,   16780,   16917,   17152,   17460,   17596,   17868,   17943,   18920,   18947,   19546,   20552,   20721,   21259,   21314,   21405,   22217,   22431,   22886,

Comment: FWIW If this is a NT textbook/exercise, I suspect they did it incorrectly (with the same error). If this is a CS problem, then just code it up.

Comment: @WillJagy You will need to generate the list till $ 17 \times 19 \times 144 = 46512$, then it cycles.

Comment: @CalvinLin alright, that won't fit in a comment

Comment: Hmm this is not a textbook problem, it was my own question which I attempted to solve but it seems that it is extremely tedious to do so.

Comment: Ah yes. Just because you can write an equation, doesn't mean that there is an easy solution. (EG Find all positive integer solutions to $a^k + b^k = c^k$.) I'm glad that at least you learnt something from this experience. I do not recommend that you find all solutions.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in the comments, it didn't work because CRT wasn't applied correctly.

In particular, the solution to $ 2^k + k \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$ has a cycle length of $ 16 \times 17$, because $2^k$ has a cycle length of 16 and $k$ has a cycle length of 17.

So, the (theoretical) approach is to find all the solutions to $2^k+k \equiv 0 \pmod{17} $ working in $\pmod{17 \times 16}$, and likewise for the other equation working in $\pmod{19 \times 18}$, and finally combine them via CRT in $ \pmod{17 \times 19 \times 144}$.

If you understand the above logic, I do not recommend actually finding all the solutions, as it's just a very tedious process that's best left to the computer.

Comment: you were correct about the 144. Program was correct, printing out was not perfect... deleted incorrect and posted anew

Answer (score 2):

Okay to solve $2^k \equiv \pmod {17}$ we know by FLT than $2^{16}\equiv 1 \pmod {17}$ and as $2^4 =16 \equiv -1$ that $2^8\equiv 1 \pmod {17}$.

So if $k \equiv 0, 1,2,3,4....,7\pmod {16}$ we have $2^k\equiv 1,2,4,8,-1,-2,-4, -8\pmod {17}$ and by CRT will be a unique solution for each pair. $k\equiv a \pmod {16}$ and $k \equiv 2^a \pmod {16}$. So that is eight solutions $\pmod {16*17}$.

(exmaple:  If $k\equiv 0\pmod {16}$ and $k \equiv 2^0=1\pmod {17}$ then $k\equiv -16 \equiv 256 \pmod {272}$.  Or if $k \equiv 1 \pmod 16$ and $k \equiv 2^1 \equiv 2\pmod {17}$ the solution $\pmod{272}$ is .... whatever)

Then we can do the same thing for $k\equiv b\pmod {18}$ and $k\equiv 2^b\pmod {19}$

So there are $18$ solutions $\pmod{18\cdot 19}$ for those.

However as $\gcd(16,18)=2\ne 1$ we must have $a,b$ either both even or both odd.

Still that is $4$ solutions $\pmod {16*17}$ with $a$ odd, and $4$ \solutions $\pmod{16*17}$ with $a$ even.  And $9$ solutions $\pmod{18*19}$ with $b$ even or odd.

So that is  $4*9=36$ solutions $\pmod{\frac {16*17*18*19}2}$ for $a,b$ odd and $36$ for $a,b$ even.

So there are $72$ solutions.

And it's way to much work do to.

But to find *one* solution we can have $k\equiv 256 \pmod {272}$

And $k \equiv 0 \pmod {18}$ and $k\equiv 2^0=1 \pmod{19}$ so $k\equiv -18\equiv 18^2 \mod {18*18}$ or $k \equiv 324 \pmod {342}$.

So if we solve $k\equiv 256\pmod {272}$ and $k \equiv 324{342}$ that solution ought to give us $2^k \equiv k\pmod {323}$ and ... oh, that $2^k - k\equiv 0$.... oh well the same ideaa will hold.

Answer (score 2):

values mod 323 and 46512 . The earlier post was in error because the final line of four numbers mod 46512 was printed below a calendar line and I did not notice them when pasting into this window...

```
Fri Mar 19 17:38:28 PDT 2021

    9   13   18   21   25   26   33   36   42   43
   49   50   52   66   67   69   72   77   83   84
   86   87   89   93   98  100  103  104  111  121
  132  134  135  138  144  154  161  166  168  172
  174  178  183  186  195  196  200  203  205  206
  208  213  217  222  229  242  253  259  263  264
  268  270  276  288  291  293  307  308  315  319
  321  322

    43    52   582   671  1820  2758  3438  3452  3574  3579
  3721  3846  4265  4405  4949  5431  5625  5975  6309  7335
  7496  8067  8345  8448  9029  9286  9563  9890 10055 10624
 10657 10842 11054 11304 11341 11440 11712 12367 12686 12697
 13018 13381 13652 13698 13834 14106 14323 14407 14604 14867
 16227 16233 16780 16917 17152 17460 17596 17868 17943 18920
 18947 19546 20552 20721 21259 21314 21405 22217 22431 22886
 22901 22946 23299 23308 23838 23927 25076 26014 26694 26708
 26830 26835 26977 27102 27521 27661 28205 28687 28881 29231
 29565 30591 30752 31323 31601 31704 32285 32542 32819 33146
 33311 33880 33913 34098 34310 34560 34597 34696 34968 35623
 35942 35953 36274 36637 36908 36954 37090 37362 37579 37663
 37860 38123 39483 39489 40036 40173 40408 40716 40852 41124
 41199 42176 42203 42802 43808 43977 44515 44570 44661 45473
 45687 46142 46157 46202
```